# How to Permanently Re-Order Columns in Parse Core?

Tags: parse-platform

I've tried many times re-ordering columns in a Parse Core Table. I tried refreshing (from the top right - built in refresh button of parse) after changing columns it looks like it saves the order but if I refresh using the browser refresh button then it goes back to the old column order.

Anyone knows how to permanently order the columns the way we want it to? Thanks in advance!